# Python: URl Pattern (update url patterns)

Tags: django

Here is my urls.py. How can I convert my old url syntax to new URL syntax?

```
[from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views, feed

    urlpatterns = patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^feed/$', feed.LatestPosts(), name="feed"),
        url(r'^', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="index"),
        url(r'^entry/(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="entry_detail"),

)][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views, feed

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^feed/$', feed.LatestPosts(), name="feed"),
        url(r'^', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="index"),
        url(r'^entry/(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="entry_detail"),
]
```

from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/

> Changed in Django 1.9: In previous versions, you had to specify both
>   the application namespace and the instance namespace in a single
>   place, either by passing them as parameters to include() or by
>   including a 3-tuple containing (,
>   , ).